# Is there an XSLT to translate from a BizTalk schema to a W3C XML Schema?

Tags: .net, xsd, biztalk

I have an XML document generated by a 3rd party using BizTalk, and I have the BizTalk schema for that document, but I need to validate the document against the schema in .NET.  When I try to load the BizTalk schema I get this message:

```
'XmlSchemaSet' can load only W3C XML Schemas
```

Is there some way, possibly an XSLT, to convert from a BizTalk schema language to the W3C XML Schema language?

Comment: Do you mean http://207.46.16.252/en-us/library/ee277698(BTS.10).aspx ?

Comment: @Alejandro: Not quite.  I don't have access to BizTalk on this end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Schema" that need to be *deployed* in BizTalk for use within the platform starts its life as plain vanilla [W3C XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema), that is a file with a `.xsd` extension.

Then, the BizTalk Visual Studio project system converts this plain XML representation of an XSD schema to a .NET class derived from [SchemaBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xlangs.basetypes.schemabase%28BTS.20%29.aspx) in a compiled .Net assembly to make it more suitable for the BizTalk runtime to consume it.

If you want to validate any given XML document against the schema in .NET, the simplest solution is to get hold of the W3C Schema file originally used as the source for the corresponding BizTalk artifact.

However, if this is not possible, you can reference the .NET assembly that contains the compiled artifact and use reflection to instantiate the generated class. Then, you can use its [Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xlangs.basetypes.schemabase.schema%28v=BTS.20%29.aspx) property to retrieve an instance of the [XmlSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.aspx) object.